# One database table very large

Tags: database, mysql

Database table Table: civicrm_contact_push_notification_messages

Is huge. 51GB to be precise.

The main field is %display_name has created activity.

Is this the table that shows up what emails have been sent under a user's activity tab? Or something else.

Does anyone know?

Thakns!
Caroline

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thats from Civimobile extension and You can find quick solution at https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/civimobileapi/-/issues/57#note_54817

> One thing I have found is editing the scheduled job Civimobile clean
> old push notification messages and setting a command / API parameter
> count_of_day=1 which means keep only 1 days worth of notification
> messages can help

Comment: That's very interesting and seems certain to fix. Just for interest - I do have civimobile extension installed but haven't really started to use it. What's the push notifications table for (given that it isn't actualy pushing anything to anyone as I'm not actually using it).